# Resistance dependent pricing for resistors

Tags: resistors, pricing

Does anybody know of any reasons that the 560 Ohm resistor is so much cheaper than the other values? It does not appear to be a trend of price increasing or decreasing with resistance since there are resistors both above and below this value that are more expensive. This is not the only example of this line. Every now and then there will be a particular value that is half the price of all the others.

[image]

Mouser.ca screenshot, 2020-10-17

Comment: Maybe they are slower moving stock and the price increased before the other lines were refilled. Doesn't matter, those are astonishing prices for resistors! So nobody (OK maybe space or military) will be buying them.

Answer (score 1):

Some values of resistors and capacitors are manufactured in much greater quantity, and thus cost less. For designs where that exact value of the resistance isn’t relevant (such as designs where the ratio of resistances determines the operation), this is perfectly fine and you can lower costs by selecting these values. If you have a very specific need, and can’t meet it with the more common resistor values, you may have to pay more to get specialized components.

Comment: 470 is a far more common resistance than 560 though. They're both E numbers though.